# Java BlockingQueue - the process doesn't want to stop

Tags: java

Why doesn't this process stop, i.e. follow the instructions even though it meets the "if" condition? What is the best way to break out of the loop in this case?

```
public class Writer implements Runnable {

    Author author;
    int i = 0;

    public Writer(Author autor) {
        this.author = autor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (i == author.getInt()) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    i++;
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println(author.getInt());
                    System.out.println("Queue txt: " + author.getQueque().take());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the `break` is reached, it will exit the `while` loop. Are you talking about the `take` method that blocks?

Comment: Have you used debugger?

Comment: This will remove `i` items from the queue, blocking if there aren't enough items, assuming `author.getInt()` always returns the same number. If it blocks, it will wait forever for some other thread to add the items it needs to the queue.

Comment: If you can't use a debugger for some reason, try System.out.println for each of the values of "i". It's most likely that the value is not what you're expecting it to be.